# Script giving error of permission denied OSerror 13 from cronjob?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, subprocess

I have written a script from the Python to automate scan. I have used nessus for that and used subprocess module in python. Problem is this it's running from the cli bash, but when I put that script to launch through by cron job. It gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/nessusscan.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['nessus','-q','-x','-T','nessus','127.0.0.1','1241','user','password','ip.txt','res'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The script is

```
subprocess.call(['nessus','-q','-x','-T','nessus','127.0.0.1','1241','user','password','ip.txt','res'])
```

Command for cron job

```
16 14 * * * cd /root/nessus; ./nessusscan.py
```

Comment: might help to post the command you used to create the cronjob

Comment: @bwbrowning posted the command plz check out

Comment: If the script is really just a single `subprocess.call(...)`, why not dispense with the whole `python` layer and make your `cron` job call `nessus -q -x ....` itself?

Comment: @twalberg  actully i m saving filenames on date basis. So that wht python is doin.But you gave a gud idea...

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the program is found by subprocess but the user running the "nessusscan.py" does not have permissions to run it.

Check ownership of the nessus file and the permissions on it.